# ExtJS: Field change event fires before ViewController's init

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6, stateful

I have a field that is stateful, and I also have it hooked up to the change event... when its value changes, I want to perform some operation. However, because it's a stateful field, the change event fires when I go back to this view, and unfortunately, the change event fires before the ViewController's init method, which means I will not be able to access my reference lookup.

In the following example, run it, change the date, and then re-run the application... you'll see a console.log that appears for the change, and then for the init. I realize I could set up the handler in the init method, but that just seems silly. I also realize I could create `myField` as a private var and access it that way, but that also seems silly. And yes, I could change to the select event, but that's not what I want to do. Anyone have any thoughts? Here's an [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12oq):

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());
        Ext.define('MyViewController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.myView',

            init: function() {
                console.log('init fired', this.lookupReference('myField'))
            },

            onChange: function(value) {
                console.log('onChange fired', this.lookupReference('myField'));
            }
        });
        Ext.define('MyView', {
            extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
            controller: 'myView',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                value: new Date(),
                stateful: true,
                stateId: 'blahblah',
                listeners:{
                    change: 'onChange'
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                value: new Date(),
                reference: 'myField'
            }]
        });
        Ext.create('MyView');
    }
});
```

Comment: in this fiddle on change don't fire automatically. I'm using Chrome and in console I only have `init fired constructor {initialConfig: Object, id: "datefield-1011", autoGenId: true, protoEl: constructor, config: Object…}`

Comment: @Marco, you have to run it twice... the first time you set a date, then you re-run the app, and you'll see my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the state mixin is initialized before the controller, this is code taken directly from Ext.Component's constructor:

```
    me.mixins.state.constructor.call(me);
    me.addStateEvents('resize');
    controller = me.getController();
    if (controller) {
        controller.init(me);
    }
```

There is no config to change this behavior. Honestly, I've never seen someone make a form field's value stateful.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured the case was... well, in our app, we have stateful datefields because our grids are filtered by date, and we'd like for users to return to these dates when they come back to the app, or we'd like to have their search queries remembered... I'm sure there's another way to accomplish this, but having it stateful is/was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `buffer` config to delay event firing. 
This has an advantage of setting up the event after the controller is initialised.

The solution:

```
listeners: {
    change: {
      buffer: 300,
      fn: 'onChange'
    }
}
```

An Alternative is to handle 'beforestaterestore` event of the stateful field and apply the state value only after controller is initialised.

```
listeners: {
  beforestaterestore: function (field, state){
     var controller = field.up().getController();

     Ext.Function.interceptAfter(controller, 'init', function(){
       field.setValue(state.value); // update
     },this);

     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: That second bit is rather interesting... I didn't know `interceptAfter` was a thing.  Thanks for sharing!